# Location service not working as expected in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios

The recent update to iOS 8.3 on my iPad mini 1 doesnt seem to have gone well with the location service.

The Location Service is enabled in the Settings but it doesnt really get my current location. When I ask Siri about my current location, it doesnt have an answer. Also, if I try to check in on Facebook App, it doesnt get the location either.

Is it a bug? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Are there other places where you can test this, to prove that it's not just an issue with where you are right now?

Comment: I cant, right now. Is anybody facing the same issue or is it just me?

Comment: I think that I previously used ver 8.1. The latest update has comletey disabled my ability to use external GPS devices and have the location aps use them to show my current location. I spent an hour on the phone with DeLorme that makes a personal tracking device. In all that time he could not get info through to his own app. Such a terrible shame. Apple in my previous IOS update had gotten to the point of working almost well with external GPS devices and getting the data to the apps. There are a lot of people depending upon location services on the iPad.

Comment: Could you update this with the exact error message siri has for you? Can siri tell you the current time?

Comment: @BrucePerkin If you want to ask a more detailed question explaining the external GPS requirement - that might help lots of people. It's not clear if Rahul is using anything other than the native location ability of the iPad Mini.

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix it is to power off the device and then open Apple Maps when it reboots.

That way you can determine if the maps app cannot work or if it's related to a temporary issue to a problem with the third party apps.

Comment: I am at the same location now as I was earlier when I faced this problem. On my second attempt with Apple Maps, I was able to get my current location. It is working very well with Siri and Facebook checkin. I dont know what happened internally but it looks like the problem has been resolved. :D

Comment: I believe the issue still exists. Even at the same location, most of the times its not able to get my location. Apple Maps says `Unable to determine location` and Siri says `I dont know where you are`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that many/most bluetooth connected GPS receivers will not work with iOS 8.3.  GPS information is received by the iPad, but the routing of this information to apps that need it has been broken by iOS 8.3.  I use a Bad Elf Pro and have experienced this problem, and know of others with bluetooth connected Dual GPS receivers that are also "dead in the water".  No legit fix (short of buying a wired GPS or one of the newer bluetooth GPS receivers that use a newer communication protocol) until Apple fixes the operating system and issues an upgrade.  My fix was to downgrade back to iOS 8.2, which you can still do as of today because Apple is "nice enough" to continue signing the iOS 8.2 firmware, but they could turn that off at any time.  A brief search on the web will show you how to do this, and it worked for me.